# How to push to the hub a docker container with two images made by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker images, one for flask BE and another for React FE. I created a docker-compose and everything goes ok. I need to push this... container?, composer? to docker hub, how can i do this? I add to this post both dockerfiles and the docker-compose.yml file.

BackEnd

```
FROM python:3.9.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN python -m nltk.downloader all

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "app:app"]
```

FrontEnd

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-composer.yml

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: flask-back
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: react-front
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose push` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @votelessbubble mentioned, you can do `docker-compose push` but only under certain conditions.

1. You are pushing an image you have built locally

   - which is in your case true for both images
2. You have access to the build key

   - now, this is where the problem lies. You need to have a private/public docker registry set in the `image` section as show in the yaml below ([link to documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_push/))

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    build: .
    image: localhost:5000/yourimage  ## goes to local registry

  service2:
    build: .
    image: your-dockerid/yourimage  ## goes to your repository on Docker Hub
```

---

What I suggest to do, is to push these images not with the `docker-compose push` command, but rather with `docker push`. The steps you need to take are following.

0. If you are using a private repository, login to that repository first

   `docker login --username=<username> --email=<email> [SERVER]`
1. Build the image

   `docker build -t <tag> .`           # replace the dot with the current location of dockerfile or inside your project
2. Push the image

   `docker push <registry>/<user>/<service>:<tag>`